# Does repentance absolve guilt?

Tags: time

Say you are a 55 year old man. You time travel back in time to when you were 15 to discuss with your former self a topic: The time you were arrested when you were 16.

Now, the 15 year old you has all intention of doing the thing that got you arrested. But you, as a 55 year old man have contemplated the issue, acknowledged you were wrong, made things right with the victims, and have moved on.

Then you start arguing about who's fault it was. That is what I would like to hear about.

Was it both of their faults, one of their faults, or neither. Thanks!

Comment: The scenario and question are both vague and unclear.  What does repentance and guilt even have to do with the scenario?  Regardless of the answer, they're both (15 and 55 year olds) idiots.  The 15 year old for having "all intention of doing the thing that [gets him] arrested".  The 55 year old for not doing something, anything, better with a *working time machine*.

Comment: Just so we're clear, is this a "single complex line" model of time travel?  I.e. when the older self was the younger self, were they visited by their older counterpart?  Or is this a Multiverse model of time travel, where the older person creates a branching timeline by travelling back?

Comment: To start, the existence of two replicas of a person simultaneously breaks causality. From there on, any analysis excluding such fact is absolutely candid and naive. Anything is possible. Perhaps guilt is the same as absolution in such context. Having two versions of such man, perhaps one commits the crime and the other doesn´t. This is like speculating if tapping with the fingers will be easy a week after two individuals have exchanged heads.

Comment: Can this question be rephrased without the fantasy setup? It's not really answerable as written.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Guru's talk about the healing power of forgiveness but they never speak the truth about the forgiveness power of healing. When the healing process is finished the guilt is absolved.

Comment: Is "repentance of *guilt*" even a thing?  Religious people can feel or be repentant **of sin**, but how can I (an atheist) be repentant of guilt (except in the generalized since of feeling bad and knowing I did wrong)?  Even then, the association with "repentance" only exists as a shorthand because "we in the West" have millennia of religious notions infusing our culture and thus our thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

The obviously correct, but also troll answer would be: You.

But your actual question would seems to be as to whether guilt, relating to the intention to do harm, would be more present in the person having actually committed the crime. And that he is now resenting his decision, trying everything imaginable or unimaginable (time travel) to make it undone (55 yo you) or in the person that exhibits the intention but hasn't yet acted upon it (15 yo you).

So that with respect to mindset the 55 yo you would be the one acting virtuous but having the actual harm as his package. While the 15 yo you would think unethical, but so far would be innocent with respect to the law.

Afaik there are several approaches to ethics such as [virtue ethics](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-virtue/), [deontology](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/ethics-deontological/) and [consequentialism](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/consequentialism/). That either empasize morals and virtues, rules and duties or try to maximize beneficial and minimize detrimental consequences.
Which consequently would prioritize the situation differently.

With respect to the actual example one would probably need more details, like did they break something mass produced with no personal value attached to it, which can be replaced and the crime be fully recovered or did they kill someone which could never be fully made undone. Did the victim face a trauma and did they ruin their life or whatnot. Ultimately it depends on whether the people you've harmed are able to forgive and move on, you showing remorse and trying to make things right is a step towards that, but whether it's sufficient is not in your hands.

Also how much guilt can be attributed to a 15 year old to begin with. The thing is it might not be a question of pure evil and malevolence, but actually about different priorities. Like the mindset of the 55 yo is unattainable to the 15 yo and he'll have a major problem putting that into words. Like idk say the 15 yo is in love for the first time and is about to do something stupid to impress his love interest. Then the 55 yo who probably went through all the highs and lows associated with being in love (maybe even multiple times) does know the feeling, but also has realized that it is not the end of the world if it doesn't work even if it might feel like that. Whereas the 15 yo quite literally can't imagine being happy in the world without that person.

All the stuff that the 55 yo will have realized "were just a phase", never feel like "just a phase" when you're in the middle of them. So maybe the person bearing the guilt was "a" 55 yo not present to tell them all of that when they were 15 or younger and everything else that contributed to them setting their priorities in a way that lead them to think committing that crime was their only viable option.

Answer (score 0):

In your scenario, your 55 year old man chose to visit his 15 year old self about a year before the offence was committed. So nobody is at fault because no offence has been committed.

Your example only makes sense to me if we suppose that the older self chose to visit his younger self so that he could dissuade himself from committing the offence in the first place. In that case, repentance and guilt are irrelevant.

If he had chosen to visit his younger self after the offence, there would be a question of fault. But it is perfectly clear that it was the fault of his younger self and that younger self will repent and make up. So it is hard to see that the visit could have any point.

There is a valid question here, whether repentance and absolution wipe the slate clean or just make the best of a bad situation.

We might suppose that younger self might be thinking that if he makes up for the offence, it is all right for him to commit it. There would then be a point to persuading his younger self that making up for an offence does not mean that it is not better to refrain from committing it in the first place.

But you don't need the time travel scenario to ask this question. Repentance and making up are making the best of a bad situation and you can call that absolution; but it will always be second best to not committing the offence.

Comment: Of course using a Time Machine to change the past can produce all kinds of nasty consequences.

Comment: Certainly. The consequences include contradictions if you wish to visit your earlier self and change something. But I felt to point that out would be obvious and boring. It seemed more interesting to concentrate on fault and repentance. After all, that's what the question was about.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a little tangential to your point about reflection and forgiveness, but I do want to point to a couple of interesting elements that the time travel science fiction brings to this.

Core to the concept is this idea of the persistence of identity across time. Time travel creates some interesting quirks here, because one (quite common) idea in time travel stories is the wish to *change* the past.  A future character regrets how things are, and they travel back in an attempt to make things otherwise.  The older self, through explaining the consequences, tries to have their younger self make different choices that lead to a different outcome.

When such change *is* possible, it comes with a couple of unusual twists.  Firstly, it’s no longer clear that “past you” in the changed past is actually the same you that you were.  Have you just created a second, different version of yourself? What happened to your 40 years of experience given that you successfully changed things?  Have your memories got to change in order to make the intervention stick? Or have you just jumped into a different world timeline, and are now just a visitor to an alternate reality where the other you has their own experiences?

Secondly, if you do assume continuity of identity, then if that change succeeded, why did you travel back in time?  The motivation to intervene followed from the consequences of the action, and so the future self who was positively influenced would not have that same motivation. However, the influence to improve comes from that motivation, so without it, you wouldn’t have improved, meaning you need your future self, motivated by negative consequences, to come back. It seems we’ve introduced a **paradox**.

The conclusion that seems to follow from the fiction is a fatalistic one - in order for this to qualify as consistent time travel, your future self can never convince your past self of the need to change course, and that through line of continuity of identity seems to be maintained.

So I think the question in the narrative of the time travelling story has to be “does future self either 1) contribute to the undesirable outcome (the tragedy of time travellers that they create their own misfortune) or 2) give information or aid that would avert it, but is ignored by the younger self (the more general tragedy of human dynamics)?”

In 1), the real life parallel is something quite specific to prodigies.  If you have a rare privilege to be able to understand the course your life would take, and that understanding is what leads you down the dark path, then that is simply a deep and abiding tragedy, in that yes, it is your own fault, with no sense of jettisoning it, and yet knowing that doesn’t really help you or anyone. You just have to come to terms with it.

In 2), this is really about growth. Your past and future selves are in different stages of life, and so while you are still the same person, you get things differently now than you did then. We change, face life’s hurdles and deal with your things as you’ve learned to. Those things are key to why you are who you are now, but we are not just entities at fixed points of reality - we extend, bend and flex our shapes along the dimensions of time and possibility, and while I certainly don’t believe in absolution, maybe you don’t have to keep living out stories of things being different to recognise that in many ways, they already are.